# Re-populating dropdown menu with database value (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, edit, populate

When going to the Edit view of a form, with values previously posted to a database, all the fields get re-populated except for the drop-down menu field.  For example, the "Surprised" value is now in the database. When I open the edit page, I only see the default 'Select Option...'

Here's what I have in my form:

```
<%= f.select :emotion, options_for_select([["Happy", "Happy"], ["Afraid", "Afraid"], ["Sad", "Sad"], ["Surprised", "Surprised"], ["Inspired", "Inspired"]]), :include_blank => 'Select Option...' %>
```

How do I get it to repopulate?

Comment: What if you remove `options_for_select` method? leave only 2 dimensional array

Comment: That did not work, same result...

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
options_for_select([["Happy", "Happy"], ["Afraid", "Afraid"], ["Sad", "Sad"], ["Surprised", "Surprised"], ["Inspired", "Inspired"]], <selected_value>)
```

Comment: Could you please give more information? I tried this, pretty much copy and pasted it, minus the angle brackets. I get this error: undefined local variable or method `selected_value' .

Comment: Note that I am coding in Rails.

Comment: Instead <selected_value> you need to pass value to be selected. In general this will be something like: my_model.emotion, where my_model is the bit you put just next to form_for.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out! Changed the value of :include_blank to be the actual variable from the database.

```
<%= f.select :emotion, ([["Happy", "Happy"], ["Afraid", "Afraid"], ["Sad", "Sad"], ["Surprised", "Surprised"], ["Inspired", "Inspired"]]), :include_blank => @table_name.emotion %>
```